# Radio button validation using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am new to Apex Oracle and PL/SQL, trying to validate radio input from the user

```
Declare    
   begin    
       if :R_button = 'NO' then
          :Page_comment != NULL;
       end if;    
   end;
```

There are three options available, YES, NO, and N/A. if the user selects No then it should prompt a comment. how best should i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.

- you already have a radio button (R_BUTTON)
- let's suppose that **return** values are

  - Y for "Yes"
  - N for "No"
  - A for "N/A"
- create a dynamic action on the radio button

  - When:

    - Event = change
    - Selection type = item
    - Item = R_BUTTON
  - Client-side condition - set it so that DA fires when radio button value is N/A

    - Type: Item = Value
    - Item: R_BUTTON
    - Value = A
  - True action

    - Action = execute JavaScript code
    - Code = `apex.message.showPageSuccess("N/A has been chosen");`
    - Affected elements: type = item
    - item = R_BUTTON

That's all. Run the page and test how it works.

This test has been made on current apex.oracle.com version (19.2):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. using the dynamic action allowed me to only show the comment box when no was entered.